# How to configure multiple EC2 instance with prefect

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, prefect

I have different EC2 instances running different jobs, and I would like to use prefect to orchestrate and schedule all the tasks.

In order to do so, do I add them as an agent and configure the IP address on docker file?

I'm pretty new to Docker and Prefect so any answer will be a great help! thanks!